# Python 3.4.2:My infinite function while loop is not working

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

My infinite `while` loop is not working as I expected it:

```
def main():
    print("Type 1 to create a file")
    print("Type 2 to read a file")
    print("Type 3 to append a file")
    print("Type 4 to calculate total of file")
    print("Type 5 to end the program")
    choice=input("Select a number:")
    if choice == '1':
            file_create(filename)
    elif choice == '2':
            read_file(filename)
    elif choice == '3':
            append_file(filename)
    elif choice == '4':
            add_numbers(filename)
```

```
filename=input("Give a name to your file:")     
while main():
    # ...
```

This executes the `main` once, but it does not loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Mr.Anyoneoutthere, Sylvain is absolutely correct. Since you don't understand it, I'll explain.
A loop needs a conditon:- True OR False.
So when you say:-

```
while True:
    print('World')
```

is the same as:-

```
a = 100
while a == 100:
    print('poop')
```

Since a == 100 would evaluate to 'True', and start a loop because you let the value remain constant, and start an infinite loop. But you can directly put the evaluation, i.e., 'True', so as to directly start an infinite loop.

As you have put:-

```
while main():
    print('World')
```

So now think... while main()... main() what?... the compiler does not get any code to evaluate something into 'True' or 'False' and the loop never starts!

So your required correct code is:-

```
while True:
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    # ...
    # <- no return statement

while main():
    # Something
```

The `while` loop loops as long as the condition is true. Here, as your `main()` function does not have a `return` statement, it doesn't return anything *explicitly*. So Python behave as if it were returning `None`. `None` is not true. So the condition is false and you don't execute the body even once.

---

What about something like that (assuming you need to execute `main()` until the user wants to quit):

```
def main():
    # ...
    print("Type 9 to quit")
    choice=input("Select a number:")
    if choice == '9':
        return False

    # Handle other cases
    if choice == '1':
        file_create(filename)
    elif choice == '2':
        # ...

    return True
```

---

On the other hand, as suggested by @thiruvenkadam in a comment below, you could keep your main as it was written in your question, but *really* write an *infinite* loop:

```
while True:
    main()
```

But that way, if you want to terminate your program gracefully , you will have to rely on some other mechanism like using exceptions...

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by its not true. how do I make it true

Comment: You either `return True` from the `main()` or call the `main()` within the while

Comment: @anyoneouthere Please take the time to read that again and compare my proposal `main` with yours: without any `return` statement a function will return `None`. If you want to keep you loop as it was written in your question, you will have to _explicitly_ return either True (to execute the loop body **and** continue looping) or something false if you want to "break" the outer while loop. If this is not quite clear, may I suggest you to take some time to experiment a little bit more with the while loop ?